# Conexión a una base de datos mysql en docker

Tags: java, mysql, docker

he tenido un problema al conectarme de un proyecto en spring boot que esta en un contenedor docker, está conectándose a una base de datos mysql que está en un docker en el mismo servidor.

Esta es la configuración que uso para todos los proyectos que he realizado en la misma máquina,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el error que obtengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es extraño porque como vuelvo a comentar, las properties son las mismas que ya he utilizado en otro proyecto para poder conectarme de la misma forma a la bd dockerizada.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

A lo que veo tienes levantado un mysql version 8.
Cuando utilizas una version 8 o superior el useSSL=false ya esta deprecado para esa version.
intenta quitando esa propiedad ó cambiandola a sslMode=DISABLED

te anexo el siguiente link para mas detalle sobre estos cambios en la versio mysql 8 y superior:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai